# How to show other vaues in a selectlist in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX to build a interactive report. There is a field in my database called method which should contain either A or B. In the edit page, I want to show a list containing A and B so that users can choose from those two.

I set the type of the item to SelectList and since I need to add the other value to the list, in the List of Values area, I set the type to PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query and the code is as follows:

```
Begin
 select TEST_METHOD into method from table_test
 where ROWID = :P2_ROWID;

 IF ('Live' = method) THEN 
   return select 'Screenshots' from dual;
 END IF;

 return select 'Live' from dual;
End;
```

However, I got the following error:

ORA-06550: line 5, column 10: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: ( - + ; case mod new not null    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date    pipe

I am new to plsql and APEX, I know the code looks wired but I don't know what's wrong. I am also wondering if there is any other way to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide any detail on what A and B are?

Comment: you have to return the sql query as a string ex:          return 'select ''Screenshots'' from dual';